Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1-\ln{x}}xdx$
$$
\mbox{Given}\ \operatorname{F}\left(x\right) \equiv
\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1-\ln\left(t\right)}{t}\,{\rm d}t,\ \mbox{calculate}\ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\operatorname{F}\left(n + 1\right) - \operatorname{F}\left(n\right)\right]
$$

I have "calculated" it geometrically, seeing that the area above the function
$\left[1-\ln\left(x\right)\right]/x$ and limited from the x-axis and the interval $\left[n,n+1\right]$ tends to $0$.
However, I would like some help to get the same result by doing the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\operatorname{F}\left(n+1\right) - \operatorname{F}\left(n\right)\right] =
\ln\left(n+1\right) - \ln\left(n\right)+\frac{\ln^2\left(n\right)-\ln^2\left(n + 1\right)}{2}
$$
I am afraid of the argument that as $n \approx n + 1$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$, we can cancel the logarithms.


The upper limit in the integral is intended to be $n,$ I guess.

For the left $\log$, you have $\log n - \log (n+1) = \log(n/(n+1)) \to \log 1= 0$, this one is true.

$\int_1^x f(x)$ creates two different meanings for $x.$ Better to write $$\int_1^x f(t),dt.$$

The indefinite integral is $\log(x)-\frac12\log^2(x).$

An alternative approach would be to use the mean value theorem

Another way of doing this. Note that for each $a_0,b_0\in [1,+\infty), a_0<b_0$, the function $f(x)=\frac{1-\log(x)}{x} \ \forall x\in [a_0,b_0]$ is continuous. Now, using the mean value theorem for integrals, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
F(n+1)-F(n)=\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1-\log(x)}{x} dx=\frac{1-\log(x_n)}{x_n},  \ n\leq x_n \leq n+1
$$
The sandwich theorem (or how you call it) gives you that $x_n\rightarrow+\infty$. It is also easy to see that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1-\log(x)}{x}=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}F(n+1)-F(n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1-\log(x_n)}{x_n}=0
$$

+1, though the MVT is not needed.

More generally, if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=C,$ and $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t),dt$$ then $F(n+1)-F(n)\to C.$

@AnneBauval jajaja true, I hadn't thought about it. That's nice!

With $F(n+1)-F(n) = \ln (n+1) - \ln n + \frac{\ln^2(n) -\ln^2(n+1)}{2}$, you can rewrite this as
$$F(n+1)-F(n) = \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) + \frac{[\ln n - \ln(n+1)][\ln n+\ln(n+1)]}{2}$$
The left-hand term goes to $\ln(1)=0$ as $n\to\infty$ so it remains to investigate the right-hand term, which is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\ln[n(n+1)] = -\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln[n(n+1)]$$
Since $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ around $0$, you have
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln[n(n+1)] \sim -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln[n(n+1)]}{n}\to 0$$

You want to compute the limit:
$$\log n - \log(n+1) + \frac{1}{2}(\log( n)^2-\log(n+1)^2)$$
as $n$ tends to infinity.
Left member
As said in my comment, you have:
$$\log n - \log(n+1) = \log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) \to_{n\to\infty} \log 1 = 0.$$
Right member
For the right term, you can notice that:
$$\log( n)^2-\log(n+1)^2 = (\log(n)-\log(n+1))(\log n + \log (n+1))$$
and then:
$$\log( n)^2-\log(n+1)^2 = \left(\log\frac{n}{n+1}\right)(\log (n(n+1)).$$
You can also note that:
$$\frac{n}{n+1} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$
Using a Taylor approximation, it comes:
$$\log( n)^2-\log(n+1)^2 = \left(-\frac{1}{n+1} + o(n^{-2})\right)\log(n^2+n).$$
You have also that $\log(n^2+n) \leq \log (2n^2) = \log 2 + 2\log n$.
The conclusion immediately follows since th function $x\mapsto \log(x)/x$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to infinity.
Hope it helps!

We have,
$$\operatorname{F}\left(x\right)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1-\ln{t}}{t}\ {\rm d}t=\int_1^x\frac{{\rm d}t}{t}-\int_1^x\frac{\ln t}{t}\ {\rm d} t=\ln x-\frac{\ln^2x}{2}$$
Now, the required limit is given by:
$$\begin{align*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\operatorname{F}(n+1)-\operatorname{F}(n)\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln(n+1)-\ln n+\frac12\left(\ln^2n-\ln^2(n+1)\right)\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)-\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\ln (n+1)-\ln n\right)\left(\ln(n+1)+\ln n\right)\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\ln(n(n+1))\right)\\&=\ln1-\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n(n+1))}{n}\qquad \text{since }\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\sim\frac{1}{n}\\&=0-\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}\qquad \text{(L'Hospital's rule)}\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\operatorname{F}(n+1)-\operatorname{F}(n)\right)&=0\end{align*}$$
Hope it helps!
